# How to implement homekit package in iphone using Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monodevelop, monotouch.dialog

How to implement homekit package in iphone using Xamarin?
I downloaded the packages from xcode 6.1, but I need to deploy to the Xamarin environment.
It is possible to implement in the environment Xamarin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin already includes HomeKit bindings in the [Monotouch.HomeKit](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=N%3AMonoTouch.HomeKit) namespace.  However, it doesn't appear that there are any samples or documentation available yet.